# Get sum of sequence using recursion

Tags: javascript

I have this sum:

[image]

Obviously, I have to get sum of that depending on what `N` is. I need to do it in three different ways.

First is `for` loop:

```js
function lab(n) {
  var S = 0;
  let VS
  if (n == 0) {
    VS = 0;
    return 0;
  }
  if (n == 1) {
    VS = 4;
    return Math.pow(3 / 5, 1);
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) { //
      S += 1 / n * Math.pow(3 / 5, n);
      t = 4 * n;
    }
    return S;
  }
}
```

Second one is recursion:

```js
function lab(n) {
  let vs = 0;
  if (n <= 1)
    return 0;
  else {
    vs += 4 * n // vs is how many actions it takes to make this calculation. I’m sure in for loop this is right, but I’m not sure about the recursion approach
    return lab(n - 1) + 1 / n * Math.pow(3 / 5, n)
  }
}
```

The third way is use recursion with the condition that in order to get S(n) I need to use S(n-1).

I am stuck on this.

Also I get different sums with the same `N`s from first and second function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking for.

If you are asking for a recursive function then take a look at the following:

```js
function summation(n, sum = 0) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return sum;
  }
  
  sum += (1/n) * Math.pow(3/5, n);

  return summation(n - 1, sum);
}

console.log(summation(1));
console.log(summation(2));
console.log(summation(3));
console.log(summation(4));
console.log(summation(5));
```

Another recursive method without passing sum as parameter:

```js
function summation(n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  return ((1/n) * Math.pow(3/5, n)) + summation(n - 1);
}

console.log(summation(1));
console.log(summation(2));
console.log(summation(3));
console.log(summation(4));
console.log(summation(5));
```

Also, for the loop method, the following will suffice

```js
function summation(n) {
  var sum = 0;
    
  while (n > 0) {
      sum += (1/n) * Math.pow(3/5, n);
      n -= 1;
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(summation(1));
console.log(summation(2));
console.log(summation(3));
console.log(summation(4));
console.log(summation(5));
```

Comment: These two are great. Also could You tell me how does the number of basic actions change when n is increasing or decreasing. I think for loop is just multiply n by 4, because there are 4 actions (1. / 2. * 3. / 4. ^) so vs=4*n. But how about recurtion?Is it still the same? It's also very confusing for me, because teacher asked us to do simple recursion and recursion that in order to get S(n) i need to use s(n-1), i mean you just did it. Is there any way to do this recursion in different way.

Comment: "I think for loop is just multiply n by 4, because there are 4 actions (1. / 2. * 3. / 4. ^) so vs=4*n". I didn't understand what you meant by "basic actions"

Comment: That is exactly what I didn't understand, what do you mean by "actions"? I am totally confused by the purpose of `VS` in your loop.
BTW is have aded another recursive method in answer

Comment: Sorry, for confusion! I'll try my best. So by saying action i mean add, subtract, divide, pow etc.
So for example this : (1/n) * Math.pow(3/5, n) has 4 action s right? first we divide, then multiply then we divide again and then we pow it. action = mathematical action. so for example in loop function if n=2, then total methematical actions = 8

Comment: Oh yes I suppose but the actual  order will be division, division, the power and then finally the multiplication. While I don't know why you need to keep track of these actions, but just passing it as parameter will be sufficient in the case of recursion which will increase by 4 in each call.